# If $\gcd(a,b) = p$, prime number then, what we can tell about the gcd of $(a^2,b^3)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $\gcd(a,b) = p$, prime number, then what we can tell about $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$?

No idea how to solve.

Comment: Can any prime other than $p$ divide $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$? What powers of $p$ necessarily divide $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$, and what powers possibly divide it?

Comment: You can use the Unique Factorization Theorem, or a bit less machinery, to show that $\gcd(a^2,b^3)=p^2$ or $\gcd(a^2,b^3)=p^3$.

Comment: Nice answers fellows. But, $p^3$ cannot divide $a^2$ right? So, the answer is not just $p, p^2?$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, How $p^3$ be $\gcd(a,b)$!

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Say $a=p^2$ and $b=p$.

Comment: @DanielFischer any suggestion?

Comment: dear @LASV, Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise the equation
$$
\frac apx+\frac bpy=1
$$
to the fourth power
$$
\frac{a^4}{p^4}x^4+4\frac{a^3}{p^3}x^3\frac bpy+6\frac{a^2}{p^2}x^2\frac{b^2}{p^2}y^2+4\frac apx\frac{b^3}{p^3}y^3+\frac{b^4}{p^4}y^4=1
$$
which is
$$
a^2p\left(\frac{a^2}{p^2}x^4+4\frac{a}{p}x^3\frac bpy+6x^2\frac{b^2}{p^2}y^2\right)+b^3\left(4\frac apxy^3+\frac{b}{p}y^4\right)=p^3
$$
Thus, $(a^2,b^3)\mid p^3$. Since $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$, we have that $p^2\mid(a^2,b^3)$. Therefore,
$$
(a^2,b^3)\in\left\{p^2,p^3\right\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to use the $p$-valuation $v_p$. We know $v_p(\gcd(a,b))=\min(v_p(a),v_p(b))=1$.

Now $v_p(\gcd(a^2,b^3)=\min(2v_p(a),3v_p(b))$ and either

- $v_p(a)=1\le v_p(b)$. Then $2v_p(a)=2<3v_p(b)$, and  $v_p(\gcd(a,b))=2$. Or
- $v_p(b)=1< v_p(a)$. Then $3v_p(b)=3$ and $2v_p(a)>2$, whence $v_p(\gcd(a,b))=3$.

For similar reasons, for any other prime $q$, $v_q(a^2,b^3)=\min(2v_q(a),3v_q(b))=0$ since one of $v_q(a), v_q(b)$ is $0$.

Comment: Don't you also have to explain why the gcd is a power of $p$?

Comment: In theory I should. In the presnt case I found it unnecessary, since it was taken for granted in the above comments.. But you're right, I'll add it for completeness.